# AVPlayer video doesn't resize after device rotation

Tags: swift, uiview, avplayer, avplayerlayer

I'm trying to make a AVPlayer video always full screen after device rotation. Here is my complete code. I do not understand why the video is not resized. Even if I use subclass like layerClass. After device rotation the videoView is cut, I do not see the video in full with. If someone has an idea. Thanks in advance.

```
import UIKit
import AVKit
import AVFoundation

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var player: AVPlayer?
    var videoView: VideoContainerView!
    var playerLayer: AVPlayerLayer!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.videoView = VideoContainerView()
        self.videoView.frame = self.view.bounds
        self.videoView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]

        let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "GAVIDEO", ofType: "mp4")
        self.player = AVPlayer(url: NSURL(fileURLWithPath: path!) as URL)
        self.player?.isMuted = true

        self.playerLayer = AVPlayerLayer(player: self.player)
        self.playerLayer.frame = self.videoView.bounds
        self.playerLayer.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravity.resizeAspectFill

        self.videoView.layer.addSublayer(playerLayer)

        self.videoView.layer.masksToBounds = true

        self.view.addSubview(self.videoView)

        self.player?.play()
    }

    override func viewWillTransition(to size: CGSize, with coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {
        super.viewWillTransition(to: size, with: coordinator)

        self.videoView.frame = self.view.bounds
        self.playerLayer.frame = self.videoView.bounds

    }

}

class VideoContainerView: UIView {

    override class var layerClass: AnyClass {
        get {
            return AVPlayerLayer.self
        }
    }

    override func layoutSublayers(of layer: CALayer) {
        super.layoutSublayers(of: layer)
        guard layer == self.layer else {
            return
        }
        layer.frame = self.bounds
    }

}
```

Comment: The problem is that `viewWillTransition` is too soon. Think about it. View _will_ transition. So the `bounds` are not the bounds you will want _after_ the transition.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

try to use the `size` from the `viewWillTransition`, doing so:

```
override func viewWillTransition(to size: CGSize, with coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {
   super.viewWillTransition(to: size, with: coordinator)
    coordinator.animate(alongsideTransition: { (context) in
    }) { (context) in
        self.videoView.frame.size = size
        self.playerLayer.frame.size = size
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Seems to work in background. Yes because when I rotate a white layer appears over the video player...

Comment: Works just great with your new updated code. Thanks a lot!

Comment: wow. 4+ years and it still working like a charm. Thank you very much @AndreaMugnaini

Answer (score 0):

The following worked for me, where `vc` is a reference to the `AVPlayerViewController` that contains the `AVPlayer` view you would like to resize.

```
override func viewWillTransition(to size: CGSize, with coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {
   super.viewWillTransition(to: size, with: coordinator)
   coordinator.animate(alongsideTransition: nil) { (context) in
      if size.height <= vc.view.bounds.height || size.width <= vc.view.bounds.width {
         vc.videoGravity = .resizeAspect
      }
      else {
         vc.videoGravity = .resizeAspectFill
      }
   }
}
```